# JavaScript GeoJson and D3.js graphs

Tags: javascript, postgresql, d3.js, leaflet, geojson

I want to visualize shape files. I already converted the shape files to GeoJson data. I should be possible that to select individual segments (circle, triangle, etc.) of the shape file. After the click on a specific segment you should be forward to a new site where I can see graphs about this specific segment. With which library can I accomplish this work?[image: Picture]

Comment: Best framework is opinion based from user to user

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: Sorry, for my formulation. I changed the question. My actual question was with which library can I accomplish this work?

Comment: your needs are general enough that you could implement it with any mapping library.  take your pick (leaflet, d3, googlemaps, etc.) and report back if you have specific questions about each.  (also FYI, you'll have much more luck if you simplify your geometries)